# FOSOAuthServerBundle - How to get User in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I implemented FOSOAuthServerBundle in my application to provide an API for mobile application. It seems to work, the user gets the `Token` and also the `RefreshToken` but if I make the controller require the user object that always returns `null`. Also fails the control of the permission, which is only `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONIMOUSLY`.

example:

```
public function showUserAction(){
   $user = $this->getUser()
   //$user = null

   $auth = $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
   //$auth = false
}
```

How to get the user object in a controller with this type of authentication?

Comment: what grant_type was used?

Comment: For now: `--grant-type="authorization_code"` `--grant-type="password"` `--grant-type="refresh_token"` `--grant-type="token"` `--grant-type="client_credentials"`
And request was performed with `grant_type=password`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you have created client with different grant_types.

NOTE: If you use **grant_type=client_credentials** during authentication, there is no User available since you do not specify exact user/password for generating token. In case of **grant_type=password** you pass username & password and token is linked to user in this case. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```